# spring mvc application hanging while inserting data from excel to mysql DB through hibernate

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have written spring mvc application that accepts excel file and then stores the excel data into the mysql DB through Hibernate.

It is working fine but after inserting 100 rows the application is hanging.

I couldn't see what is the error for hanging.In the console it shows nothing.

Comment: if you are debugging the application click on the "pause" debugger button to see what your app is doing of hanging on.

Comment: Let me guess, you have a connection pool with 100 connections (max)...

Comment: had u solved this issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry guys I didn't write session.close() in my method.It resolved my issue.But I don't know what is the connection between session.close() and application hanging.